# steder11icra for electric

Tags: ros, ros-pcl, object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to experiment on http://www.ros.org/wiki/Papers/ICRA2011_Steder code. Its developed for cturtle. Will that be compatible with electric? Any unstable version available on ros-electric?
Even the existing package is not getting downloaded. I get the following error when i do the rosinstall of the config file given in the link.

```
ERROR: Failed to install tree '/workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_steder11icra/steder11icra/steder11icra_ros/ros'
 Checkout of https://code.ros.org/svn/ros/stacks/ros/tags/cturtle -r10573 version  into /workspace/karthik/RRC/ros_steder11icra/steder11icra/steder11icra_ros/ros failed.
```

Thanks,
Karthik

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12443/steder11icra-for-electric/) by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the paper's wiki page, section 5:

> Please note, that the code presented below was tested on Ubuntu 9.10 and apparently does not work anymore under newer Ubuntu versions (because of some of the outdated ROS packages). If you are interested in using NARFs, they are implemented in the Point Cloud Library (PCL): http://www.pointclouds.org and the tutorials on ros.org: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials

It seems unlikely that you'll be able to get it running with Electric or Unstable on a current version of Ubuntu. Your best bet it to do as the wiki page suggests and use the NARF implementation in PCL.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2